# How to tell if vim is being run in command line vs. powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, vim

I would like to make a function which does the following

```
if (vim is running in powershell)
    call system("only works in powershell")
else
    echo "Skipping powershell command"
```

Does anyone know how to tell what program vim is being run from?

EDIT: `echo &term` outputs "win32" in both cases.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From what I see you don’t need to check what vim was run from. You need to check the value of `&shell` because vim will run command in powershell if `&shell` option tells it to run command in powershell. If name of the shell is `posh` then checking may be done with

```
if stridx(&shell, 'posh')!=-1
    call system('only works in powershell')
else
    echo 'Skipping powershell command'
endif
```

. But I would rather suggest to run powershell directly with something like

```
call system('posh -c '.shellescape('only works in powershell'))
```

(note: I am not sure about what `'posh -c '` string should actually look like) or temporary set &shell option:

```
let savedsh=[&shell, &shellcmdflag, &shellxquote, &shellxescape, &shellquote, &shellpipe, &shellredir]
set shell=posh shellcmdflag=-c shellxquote=\" shellquote=\" shellpipe=> shellredir=>
try
    call system('only works in powershell')
finally
    let [&shell, &shellcmdflag, &shellxquote, &shellxescape, &shellquote, &shellpipe, &shellredir]=savedsh
endtry
```

(again, not sure about exact values of options): these ways command will always run in powershell.

Answer (score 3):

You can check `$term`. For example on my `cygwin` and `git bash`, I get `$term` as  `cygwin`.

For Powershell, you may set in your profile the following and check against that:

```
$env:TERM = "posh"
```

Note that `&shell` will cmd.exe for both cmd and powershell.