# How to set different colorscheme in VIM while running in Powershell?

Tags: powershell, vim

How to make VIM recognize that is running in Powershell and apply colorscheme that I want?

In other words: `IF running in powershell THEN colorscheme ...`

Comment: Actually I think this one has the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11915895/how-to-tell-if-vim-is-being-run-in-command-line-vs-powershell?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

[How to tell if vim is being run in command line vs. powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11915895/how-to-tell-if-vim-is-being-run-in-command-line-vs-powershell?rq=1)

...this one didn't work for me, however I found "the other way around solution":

```
colorscheme ir_black

if has('gui_running')
  set guifont=Inconsolata:h12
  colorscheme native
endif
```

First `colorscheme` will work for Powershell, and the one inside `if-endif` will work when gVim is running outside the Powershell.

Comment: What part of it didn't work?

Comment: The whole thing didn't work, however now I found that it does actually work, but only when it's preceeded with `set shell=posh`.