# vimscript: how to tell if vim is running in command prompt and powershell

Tags: shell, powershell, vim

I found another same question solved in stackoverflow but that solution doesn't work for me:
[How to tell if vim is being run in command line vs. powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11915895/how-to-tell-if-vim-is-being-run-in-command-line-vs-powershell)
The solution use `stridx(&shell, 'posh') != -1` to tell vim is running in powershell.
So I tried `:echo` the `stridx(&shell, 'posh')` in vim running in Windows **Command Prompt**, **PowerShell**, **Shell Terminal**, **GVim** and **MacVim**.
All of them echoed `-1`. That means it doesn't work.
So please forgive me to ask this question again.
I install a vim plugin [Colorizer](https://github.com/chrisbra/Colorizer) and then I found it will cause errors when I'm editing in **Command Prompt** or **PowerShell**. So I want to add an if condition in _vimrc to avoiding auto command `ColorHighlight` when I'm running vim in **Command Prompt** or **PowerShell**.
I tried to use `has("feature")` with features `dos16` `dos32` etc.. but cannot find a good one.

Comment: `:echo &shell` in different console, what are the outputs?

Comment: @mts You cannot add the comment or edit the question without approval because you happened to log out and create a new user with the same name.

Comment: Author of the Colorizer plugin here. Please use the issue tracker to describe more clearly what your problem is

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt I added an [issue](https://github.com/chrisbra/Colorizer/issues/39), please check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`&shell` is a setting that tells Vim what shell it should use for bang commands (`:!`, `read !`, `:w !`), `system()`, `&*prg` options. It has absolutely nothing to do with the shell from which Vim is run *except* that the default value is taken from environment.

`has('feature')` is used to determine what features Vim has and its result is usually hardcoded at the compile time. Shell from which Vim was started is not a Vim feature, so there `has()` is of no use even though there are some “features” that are determined at runtime (e.g. `has('interpreter')` given Vim compiled with `+interpreter/dyn` or `has('gui_running')`).

The only way to do this is system dependent: run shell, get its process ID (`$$` in *nix shells, dunno about Windows ones) (Vim has no means of gettings its own process ID) and check which process is the parent of the given processes parent in that shell (parent of the parent of the shell is Vim parent), then check out the name of the process. If you have Vim with interpreters support you may get Vim process ID directly; Python + psutil should work even on Windows:

```
python << EOF
def myscript_get_parent_process_name():
    import psutil
    return psutil.Process().parent().name()
EOF

if stridx(pyeval('myscript_get_parent_process_name()'), 'posh') != -1
    " Powershell code
endif
```

Comment: Thank you, but I have no idea how to use the code you give. I haven't learn python yet.

Comment: @mts There are only three lines of Python, everything else is VimL; with the example of usage. You do need to install Python and psutil python module in any case, thus it may be better to find out how to do the same thing with the shell.

Comment: Thank you, it works. Take me hours to install python + psutil and fix some errors, but it works.